# How to display received bytes as text in java?

Tags: java, sockets, delphi

first of all , i am very new to programming , and a task im trying to accomplish is :

> send bytes from my delphi program to java server(**done**!)
>
> display **received bytes** as text in a java server

**T H E Question :**  How to display received bytes in java?

Thank you very mutch if you could help, that would save me atleast one more sleepless night.

My **working** code example from delphi application:

```
procedure sendInt(val: integer);
begin
  Socket.SendByte(byte(val shr 24));
  Socket.SendByte(byte(val shr 16));
  Socket.SendByte(byte(val shr 8));
  Socket.SendByte(byte(val));
end;
```

The java server code i was able to put together , probably a nonsence.

```
ServerSocket sc=new ServerSocket(9999);
Socket s=sc.accept();
DataInputStream dos=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
String msg=dos.readUTF();
System.out.println(msg);
```

What this **does** : If i  run the java server, and send the bytes - returns null.
If i send continuous bytes - server does nothing, and only after i finish sending it displays a whole bunch of nulls, not sure if that helps, just trying to give as mutch information as possible. Thank you !

Comment: You can use the `String` constructor [that takes bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and print the result.

Comment: Is the `val` that you're sending a string or a number? It looks like you should be reading an `int` instead of a string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, val is integer , it was my understanding that reading a string and an integer in java is the same procedure, i'm just that green

Comment: Advice: if you don't know what a method does, do not guess, look it up in the API doc. For example, [readUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF) expects a special format of the underlying byte stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass through and display an int32 as formatted in your stream (you're sending big-endian), then the conceptually easiest way is:

```
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
int val = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    val <<= 8; // does nothing first time
    val |= is.read();
}
System.out.println(val);
```

This assembles the received bytes into an int32 and prints it as a formatted string with newline.

Comment: Didn't know you can post two answers... learn something new everyday.

Comment: Meh, and nowhere in the UI to delete it.  Yuck.

Comment: Thank you so mutch for help! I have tried adding your code , but the compiler returns the following:
error: cannot find symbol
    val |= s.read();
            ^
is there something that might actally be wrong with the code, or is it all me?

Comment: Also I just tried the technique and it works well for negative numbers AFAICT.

Comment: Well, then its something wrong with my code probably, because i am getting -1 ,
anyways, a huge thank you for trying to help! Thats it for tonight, going to have get myself to learn java !

Comment: I've added a working pastebin for client and server at http://pastebin.com/rLf2U1Gm

Comment: Thank you, going to test it tommorow.

Comment: The delete button lets you delete answers

Comment: Maybe, but I don't have one of those.  Perhaps when I exceed 1,000 rep?  I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did intend to reconstruct a String, then [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [LineNumberReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) are your friends.

Java is notable as one of the few platforms that hard-enforces charset management (e.g. Unicode), so you can't trivially interchange bytes and chars. But you can do something like:

```
LineNumberReader lines = new LineNumberReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        s.getInputStream()
    )
);
String someLine = lines.readLine();
```

...and, of course, dealing with exceptions.  The InputStreamReader lets you do read() against the byte stream as chars (and, note, that UTF8 encoding is default, but NOT the only encoding you could use), and the LineNumberReader let's you pull line-by-line instead of char-by-char.

Of course, if you want char-by-char, you could use read() and lose LineNumberReader entirely.  Something like:

```
// 4 chars only
char buf[4];
reader.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
String s = new String(buf);
```

Also, be careful with invalid Unicode byte sequences.  See the InputStreamReader docs for pointers to dealing with Charsets.

Comment: what does `LineNumberReader.readLine ()` do that BufferedReader doesn't?  Seems rather strange to use LineNumberReader

Comment: Personal preference really; I like having access to the line number counter and there is no real performance or compatibility penalty.  BufferedReader is just about as good for this use case.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for such a detailed response BJ Black,  Does linenumber reader also applies if i need to read int? I really just need to display the received int in the cmd